# eslint does not warn on non existing class method

Tags: reactjs, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

I have setup `eslint` with my react project. My eslint config simply extends `airbnb`.
It works as expected and warns about things like `'class-methods-use-this'`, etc. But it does not warn me if i try to use a class method with `this.nonexistingmethod()` . Is this expected behaviour? shouldn't there be a rule for it? 
( I tried looking for an existing rule by googling but couldn't find it )

Windows 8.1, vscode, react 16

Comment: This isn't something ESlint is supposed to help with. Use static typing, like Flow or Typescript.

Comment: Wouldn't it be similar to how it checks for undeclared variables or undefined functions without 'this'

Comment: No, because variables in current scope can be confidently analyzed, while `this` properties can't. Also, `this` may be dynamic and refer to anything in JS.